# CocoaLumberjack Undefined Symbols building for simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, cocoalumberjack

I am upgrading my code to use Swift 3 and CocoaLumberjack 3.0.0. When I build for the iPhone is compiles and links successfully. When I try building for the simulator it compiles but will not link. I get several messages of the form:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "CocoaLumberjack.DDLogDebug (@autoclosure () -> Swift.String, level : __C.DDLogLevel, context : Swift.Int, file : Swift.StaticString, function : Swift.StaticString, line : Swift.UInt, tag : Any?, asynchronous : Swift.Bool, ddlog : __ObjC.DDLog) -> ()", referenced from:
      ScanmonListener.SMLViewController.buttonTitle.didset : Swift.String in SMLViewController.o
      ScanmonListener.SMLViewController.viewDidLoad () -> () in SMLViewController.o
      ScanmonListener.SMLViewController.viewDidAppear (Swift.Bool) -> () in SMLViewController.o
      ScanmonListener.SMLViewController.viewDidDisappear (Swift.Bool) -> () in SMLViewController.o
      ScanmonListener.SMLViewController.viewWillAppear (Swift.Bool) -> () in SMLViewController.o
      ScanmonListener.SMLViewController.viewWillDisappear (Swift.Bool) -> () in SMLViewController.o
      ScanmonListener.SMLViewController.doPlay () -> Swift.Bool in SMLViewController.o
      ...`

I have run `pod deintegrate` and installed again with no effect.

Answer (score 1):

-->Solution: In each of the "Pod_" targets you must add `x86_64` (and, perhaps, `i386`) to the `Valid Architectures` Build Settings.